# Align parent div to the center horizontally

Tags: css

I have this:

```css
figure {
  display:inline-block;
}

figcaption {
  width:0;
  min-width:100%;
}
```

```html
<figure>
   <img src="https://i.imgur.com/k1Crowy.jpg" width="200">
   <figcaption> This is some random text that should not expand the figure tag beyond the width of the img tag </figcaption>
</figure>
```

How can I align the `<figure>` tag to the center, *without* breaking the `figcaption` width fix *and* without adding an outer div?

### What I've tried so far

I can do the `margin:0 auto` approach to the child tags, but that will break the `figcaption` width fix.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `display:table` and you will have a similar behavior as `inline-block` then you can consider `margin:auto`

```css
figure {
  display:table;
  margin:auto;
}

figcaption {
  width:0;
  min-width:100%;
}
```

```html
<figure>
   <img src="https://i.imgur.com/k1Crowy.jpg" width="200">
   <figcaption> This is some random text that should not expand the figure tag beyond the width of the img tag </figcaption>
</figure>
```

Answer (score 1):

added below `CSS` to `figure`

```
  margin-left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
```

```css
figure {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}

figcaption {
  width: 0;
  min-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<figure>
  <img src="https://i.imgur.com/k1Crowy.jpg" width="200">
  <figcaption> This is some random text that should not expand the figure tag beyond the width of the img tag </figcaption>
</figure>
```

Comment: note that this may create unwanted overflow because margin-left will be added to the width of the element and in small screen this will exceed the total width of the container. (more presicely when the width of figure is also equal to 50% of the parent width)

Comment: here is an example with a bigger image: https://jsfiddle.net/gdmovrnt/ see the scroll you have at the bottom due to the *unwanted overflow* because the width of the figure + 50% of margin is more than the total width

Answer (score -1):

for image or figure tag, you can use :

```
display: block;
margin:auto
```

and for every tag like , you can use :

```
position: absolute;
left: 50%;
top:50%;
transform: translate(-50%, -50%)
```

in this case, your code must be :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
    <style>
        div {
            width: 500px;
            height: 400px;
            border: 1px solid grey
        }

        .hoz {
            position: absolute;
            left:50%;
            transform: translate(-50%);
        }
        .center {
            position: absolute;
            left:50%;
            top:50%;
            transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

<div>
    <figure>
        <img src="https://i.imgur.com/k1Crowy.jpg" width="200" style="display: block;margin:auto">
        <figcaption> This is some random text that should not expand the figure tag beyond the width of the img tag </figcaption>
    </figure>
</div>

<div style="position: relative">
    <figure class="hoz" style="margin:0">
        <img src="https://i.imgur.com/k1Crowy.jpg" width="200">
        <figcaption> This is some random text that should not expand the figure tag beyond the width of the img tag </figcaption>
    </figure>
</div>

<div style="position: relative">
    <figure class="center" style="margin:0">
        <img src="https://i.imgur.com/k1Crowy.jpg" width="200">
        <figcaption> This is some random text that should not expand the figure tag beyond the width of the img tag </figcaption>
    </figure>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```